# mount and loop0 preempting user processes for long time

Tags: process, linux-kernel, kernel, real-time, preemption

I created some processes in user space and tried to visualize its working in *kernelshark* with the trace recorded using *trace-cmd*. But processes like the ones shown below are preempting my processes with real-time priority 98 as long as 4 seconds. These kind of processes don't even have a real-time priority

```
PID  PPID CLS PRI RTPRIO CMD

359     1 TS   19      - mount.ntfs /dev/disk/by-uuid/AC72763B72760A7A /root
366     2 TS   39      - [loop0]
```

What can I do to run my processes uninterrupted by these kind of kernel processes?

Comment: In your process, are you performing and disk read/write upon a file in a NTFS partition on your disk?

Comment: no. I am writing to a shared memory location in one process and reading from the others and execute few commands. The processes that read from the shared memory are periodic and are activated every 10 ms.